# SQL #1064 Error

Tags: php, sql, database

I am having some difficulty in adding to an existing database. I am using the following code but it comes up with a '#1064' error saying: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE = MYISAM COMMENT = 'This table is the list of Patients types (e.g Day or Bo' at line 1

```
    CREATE TABLE `MRC_patients_types` ( `patients_types_id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `patients_types_name` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY ( `patients_types_id` ) , INDEX ( `patients_types_name` ) ) TYPE = MYISAM COMMENT = 'This table is the list of Patients types (e.g Day or Boarding)'; 

    INSERT INTO `MRC_patients_types` ( `patients_types_name` ) VALUES ('Day'), ('Boarding');

    ALTER TABLE `MRC_patients` ADD `patients_type` BIGINT AFTER `patients_year` ;
```

Any advice as to what is not right would be much appreciated.
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `TYPE = MYISAM` to `ENGINE = MYISAM`

Answer (score 2):

Use `ENGINE` instead of `TYPE`

> TYPE keyword is depreciated (since 5.0) and not supported in MySQL5.5

```
CREATE TABLE `MRC_patients_types` 
( 
   `patients_types_id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `patients_types_name` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( `patients_types_id` ) , 
    INDEX ( `patients_types_name` ) 
) 
ENGINE = MYISAM 
COMMENT = 'This table is the list of Patients types (e.g Day or Boarding)';
```